# How do I use self type in a header file in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, header-files, self

I need to define a protocol inside my class, one of the method need the type of this class as parameter, how do I use self type here?

code:

```
//  myClass.h

@protocol delegate
- (void)method:(myClass *)myClass;
@end

@interface myClass : UIView

// some properties and methods

@end
```

It gives the error that "Expected a type" which indicates that myClass is not recognized as a type.

Comment: put `@protocol delegate` below the `@interface myClass`

Comment: FYI - standard naming convention state that class and protocol names should start with uppercase letters. Method and variable names start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

use "@class myClass;" up to @protocol delegate

Answer (score 0):

plz define protocol below of your class

```
@interface myClass : UIView

// some properties and methods

@end

@protocol mydelegate <NSObject>

- (void)method:(myClass*)myClass;

@end
```

Comment: This won't work in the likely case that the interface needs to declare a `delegate` property which will require a reference to the protocol.